# Oracle update with subquery alias

Tags: oracle, join, sql-update

I have two tables:

```
**PRODUCTS**:  
*PART   ITEM*  
M1      A1  
M1      A2  
M1      A3  
M2      B1  
M2      B2  
M3      C1  
M3      C2  
...  

**PARTS**:
*PART   CODE*
M1      XYZ
M2      XYZ
M3      ABC
A1      XYZ
A2      MNO
A3      <null>
B1      <null>
B2      <null>
C1      <null>
...
```

Basically, I want to update the nulls in the PARTS table by
  - taking one of the existing codes from PARTS.CODE
  - where PART.PART = PRODUCT.PART
  - matching PARTS.PART on PRODUCT.ITEM

What I have so far is:

```
update PARTS t2 
set t2.CODE =
  (
    select tx.CODE, t1.ITEM
    from PARTS tx
    join PRODUCTS t1
      on  tx.PART = t1.PART
  ) a
where t2.PART = a.ITEM
  and t2.CODE is null
```

The inner select brings up the ITEM and CODE that I need - at least it looks like it will match in the 'where' below that.  The error I'm getting is:
  **Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended**

Thanks much...

Answer (score 3):

```
update PARTS t2 
set t2.CODE = (select max(tx.CODE) 
                 from PARTS tx join PRODUCTS t1 on tx.PART = t1.part
                where t2.part = t1.item
              )
where t2.CODE is null
  and exists(select 1 from PRODUCTS t1 where t1.item = t2.part and t2.part = t1.part);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting 0 rows updated, but there are 8 _nulls_ currently, so I need to mess with it a bit.

Comment: @user1628169 Yes, your condition looks strange: "where PARTS.PART = PRODUCT.PART and PARTS.PART = PRODUCT.ITEM"

Comment: Think I have it - worked a couple times, need to test some more.  Some slight changes:

    update PARTS t2
    set t2.CODE =
      (
        select tx.CODE
     -- select max(tx.CODE)
        from PRODUCTS t1  -- flipped
        inner join PARTS tx  -- flipped
          on t1.PART = tx.PART
        where t2.PART = t1.ITEM
      )
    -- where t2.CODE is null
    --   and exists  
    where exists
      (
        select t1.PART
        from PRODUCTS t1
        where t2.PART = t1.ITEM -- rmvd "and" line
      )